# How do i use the pygame to make a score list

Tags: python, sql, pygame

I followed the pygame tutorial finished [like this](https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/blob/master/Pygame/39_PythonGameDevelopment.py)

But if i want to let the user input their nickname then  output the score list(sorted)

How could i do?

Comment: PyGame doesn't have element/widget to get user input. There are some (old) GUI modules for PyGame and you can find it (http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui) or you will have to create own input widget.

Comment: you have [pygame.font](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) to render text.

Answer (score 1):

### Blitting Fonts

This is how the program created the font objects:

```
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25) #(font type, font size)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)
```

You then need to create a surface using the Font object.  An example of this exists in the program:

```
text = smallfont.render("Score: "+str(score), True, black)
```

It is then blitted like this:

```
gameDisplay.blit(text, [0,0])
```

### Saving Scores

To save an array to a file, you need to import pickle.  Try the following code, as an example:

```
import pickle, os

if os.path.isfile("/home/username/Pickling_Program/scores.txt"): #insert filename here
    f = open("/home/username/Pickling_Program/scores.txt", "r")
    scores = pickle.load(f)
    print scores
    f.close()
else:
    print "No scores saved."

scores = []
for a in range(10):
    scores.append(["", 0])

for a in range(10):
    scores[a][0] = raw_input("Type name:")
    scores[a][1] = raw_input("Type score:")

f = open("/home/username/Pickling_Program/scores.txt", "w")
pickle.dump(scores, f)
f.close()
```

I haven't been able to test this program, but it should work.  Mention any errors in the comments so I can fix them.

I'm not going to show you exactly what steps to take to do this, because not only do I not have time, but you also wouldn't learn anything.  What you need to do to do this is to take the score the player gets, load the score file, and see if it is larger than the lowest value.  If it is, you add it into the score list, remove the lowest score, sort the list again, and save it.  You would then take the scores and display them on the screen.  Refer to the following websites so you can do what you are trying to do, and more:

*"Give a man a fish, and he'll eat for a day.  Teach a man to fish, and he'll have food for the rest of his life.*

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

http://www.pygame.org/docs/

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

Hope this helped!